# Enable hashbang in $http URL in AngularUS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to access an URL in AngularJS as

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/#/notebook/2CG2BVYJ1")      
          .then(function(response){ vm.getgraph = response.data; });
```

For this, the get request sent is only http://localhost:8080/. I think $http.get is ignoring anything after '#' in the URL. How to make it access the full URL?

Answer (score 0):

If this is is from the same app I will suggest you can use get in more direct way like so

```
$http({
method: 'GET',
url: '/notebook/2CG2BVYJ1'
}).then(function(response){ vm.getgraph = response.data; });
```

> I hope this help